# Authorizing REST API calls to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am totally new to GCP products. I am trying to create and manage the resources i.e. Virtual Machines using the REST API's provided in the documentation. One of the endpoints which I am trying is

```
GET https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances?key={API_KEY}
```

Though to make authorized calls to the platform I need to configure the OAuth 2.0 authentication for which I created the relevant service account. I am not sure how to further use it to authorize the requests. Any leads on this would be greatly helpful. Thanks!

**Edit:**
I intend to call the REST APIs from Python. Not sure if that's the right way.

Comment: Do you need how to generate an API key?

Comment: This is probably a good place to get started ... https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Comment: I have generated the API key which I pass as a path parameter. Further to authorize the request I need to pass the Authorization header which requires a token of OAuth 2.0, I want to know about generating OAuth 2 Bearer token.

Comment: @Kolban Thanks for the lead. Though I checked out the documentation you provided it is quite unclear to me about generating the OAuth token which is supposed to be passed as a header

Comment: Maybe try this ... https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2   ... you might also want to look at one of the client libraries.  Making REST calls directly is the lowest level API possible.

Comment: @Kolban Again Thank you for the reference. This document provides steps to authenticate the requests from client libraries i.e Python just for Cloud Storage. I am unsure of the Compute Engine libraries.

Comment: The protocol is the same for both services

Comment: Forget the API key, it is here for legacy reason  but useless!

Comment: From the document referenced by @Kolban, it suggested to create JWT tokens and get authorized. I created the JWT token but unable to authorize it with Google API now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to authorize the API calls to GCP by creating JWT, serializing it to UTF-8 representation (UTF-8 is important), signing it using the google client library `google.auth` and finally making a request to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` having passed `POST` parameters `grant_type = urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` and `assertion` whose value is the signed jwt for the token using the signed JWT token.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2